# python for loop for multiple condition in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code:

```
for x in range(0, 7) + 100:
    print x
```

Expected output:

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 100
```

Please help me get this output.

Below is the error of the code:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Python 2, range is creating a list.
To add a number to the end of a list, first put it in a list, then you can use the addition operator:

```
for x in range(0, 7) + [100]:
```

(To do this in python 3, you will need to convert the range into a list, as it `range(...)` creates a different datatype):

```
for x in list(range(0, 7)) + [100]:
```

Comment: @idjaw No, I knew it would work, but I just tested it and it worked as expected.

Comment: I just saw the python2.7 tag. Right! In Python 2.7 `range` actually creates a list. That's why that works. In Python 3 that is not the case since it carries over the functionality of what `xrange` does in Python 2. Doing that in Python 3 will result in: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'list'`. Even though the tag states Python2.7, it might help to provide some of that detail in the answer considering it could be easily missed by future readers.